# Sentry not logging errors in console but it works logs in sentry.io

Tags: angular, sentry

Below is my code of sentry init()

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: environment.sentryDsn,
  ignoreErrors: [/Loading chunk +[\d]+ failed/, 'ChunkLoadError'],
  environment: environment.production ? 'superb-production' : 'superb-dev',
  integrations: [
    new Sentry.Integrations.Breadcrumbs({
      console: true
    }),
    new Sentry.BrowserTracing({
      // Set `tracePropagationTargets` to control for which URLs distributed tracing should be enabled
      tracePropagationTargets: [
        environment.projectsUrl,
        environment.apiBaseAddress
      ],
      routingInstrumentation: Sentry.routingInstrumentation
    }),
    // Registers the Replay integration,
    new Sentry.Replay({
      maskAllText: false,
      maskAllInputs: false,
      blockAllMedia: false
    })
  ],
  beforeSend(event) {
    const sentryException = new SentryException();
    const isBlockErrorLoging = sentryException.filterSentryException(event);
    if (isBlockErrorLoging) return null;
    else return event;
  },
  // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100% of transactions for performance monitoring.
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  // Capture Replay for 10% of all sessions, plus for 100% of sessions with an error
  replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
  replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0
});

// Set the tracesSampler in globalOptions to customize the sampling rate based on request origin
Sentry.setExtras({
  tracesSampler: (samplingContext: any) => {
    // Get the request origin
    const requestOrigin =
      samplingContext.rootSpan &&
      samplingContext.rootSpan.data &&
      samplingContext.rootSpan.data.request &&
      samplingContext.rootSpan.data.request.url.origin;

    // Define your domain origin here
    const allowedDomainOrigin = environment.projectsUrl;

    // Sample only requests from your domain
    return requestOrigin === allowedDomainOrigin ? 1.0 : 0.0;
  }
});
```

This is above my sentry logs code. This is working for sentry logs but when any type of error occurred then not showing in the console. so How do we log errors in the console with this implementation?